# Django(2.0.6): update m2m related objects in signals

Tags: python, django

I was kind of trying to get updated related objects list from m2m field

E.g. I have following models

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(default='N/A')
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, default=10.00)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path, null=True, blank=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    category = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20, choices=CATEGORIES)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=AVAILABLE_SIZE, blank=True)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=AVAILABLE_CHOICE, blank=True)

    objects = ProductManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/products/{slug}/".format(slug=self.slug)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    subtotal = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = CartManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Now I update my "products" field via django admin by just removing and adding items.

So I expect that the signal below, will print updated product (which I have just added/removed ). However, I'm still getting all the products (all products from Product model)

```
def m2m_changed_cart_receiver(sender, instance, action, *args, **kwargs):
    if action == 'post_add' or action == 'post_remove' or action == 'post_clear':
        print(action)
        products = instance.products.all()
        print(products)
        total = 0
        for x in products:
            total += x.price
        if instance.subtotal != total:
            instance.subtotal = total
            instance.save()


m2m_changed.connect(m2m_changed_cart_receiver, sender=Cart.products.through)
```

I'm new to django, anyone can shed some light will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pk_set

try :

```
pk_set = kwargs.pop('pk_set', None)
```

For the pre_add, post_add, pre_remove and post_remove actions, this is a set of primary key values that have been added to or removed from the relation.

For the pre_clear and post_clear actions, this is None.

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#m2m-changed)